# Multiple downloads and update progress bar for each

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-file, android-download-manager

I have a recyclerview of books. When the user clicks on a book, a fragment launches with 2 buttons where the user can:

1. Read the Book
2. Download the Book

If the user wants to download the book, a progress bar appears at the top of the fragment with a caption displaying:

```
Downloading page <n> of <total pagecount>
```

The caption and progress bar updates until the download finishes. The user can press the back button and download another book. If the user chooses to go back to the first book, the fragment should launch with the current updated progress of the download.

How best to implement this feature?

**Some things I tried:**

1. I tried creating an AsyncTask in the fragment. But when the user presses "back", the task stops.
2. I created an interface and let the activity do the download instead of the fragment. I can do multiple downloads now but am having problems retrieving the progress from the activity and showing it in the fragment. Sometimes, the progress bar and caption don't update at all. Also, my app became very slow and sometimes unresponsive.

**In Fragment:**

```
fragmentCallback!!.downloadBook(activity, book, object : DownloadBookProgressCallback {
                            override fun downloadProgress(page: Int) {
                                uiThread {
                                    progressBar!!.progress = page
                                    progressText!!.text = "Downloading page " + page + " of " + book.content!!.pageCount!!
                                }
                            }
                        })
```

**Interfaces:**

```
interface FragmentCallback {
    fun downloadBook(context: Context, book: ResourcesList, downloadBookProgressCallback: DownloadBookProgressCallback)
    fun getDownloadProgress(bookId: Int):Int
    fun getDownloadStatus (bookId: Int) : Boolean
    fun getMaxPages (bookId: Int) : Int
}
```

**In Activity**

```
 override fun downloadBook(context: Context, book: ResourcesList, downloadBookProgressCallback: DownloadBookProgressCallback) {
            val downloadInstance = DownloadBook()
            activeDownloadBooks[book.id] = downloadInstance
            downloadInstance.gettingPages(context, book.content!!.pageCount!!, book, downloadBookProgressCallback)
    }

    override fun getDownloadStatus(bookId: Int): Boolean {
        val retrieveInstance = activeDownloadBooks[bookId]

        if (retrieveInstance != null) {
            return retrieveInstance.getDownloadStatus()
        }

        return false
    }

    override fun getDownloadProgress(bookId: Int): Int {
        val retrieveInstance = activeDownloadBooks[bookId]
        if (retrieveInstance!!.getDownloadStatus()) {
            return retrieveInstance.getProgress()
        } else {

        }
        return 0
    }

    override fun getMaxPages(bookId: Int): Int {
        val retrieveInstance = activeDownloadBooks[bookId]
        return retrieveInstance!!.getMaxPages()
    }
```

**Download Class**

```
class DownloadBook {
    private var isDownloading : Boolean = false
    private var currentPage = 0
    private var maxPages = 0
    var sp : SharedPreferences? = null

    fun gettingPages(ctx : Context, pageCount : Int, book : ResourcesList, callback: DownloadBookProgressCallback) {
        maxPages = pageCount
        for (page in 1..pageCount) {
            isDownloading = true
            println("getting page " + page + " " + book.name)
            currentPage = page
            callback.downloadProgress(page)
            var a = book.content!!.pageURI + page

            println(a)
            val bmap: Bitmap = Picasso.get().load(a).get()


            val cw = ContextWrapper(ctx)

            val directory = cw.getDir("BookId" + book.id.toString(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            val mypath = File(directory, "page" + page + ".jpg")

            var fos: FileOutputStream
            try {
                fos = FileOutputStream(mypath)
                bmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos)
                fos.close()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("DOWNLOAD_BOOK", e.message, e)
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

        }

        sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx)
        val editor = sp!!.edit()
        println("Saving to shared prefs: " + book.name)
        editor.putString(book.id.toString(), book.content!!.pageCount.toString())
        editor.apply()

        isDownloading = false
    }



    fun getDownloadStatus() : Boolean {
        return isDownloading
    }

    fun getProgress() : Int {
        return currentPage
    }

    fun getMaxPages() : Int {
        return maxPages
    }
}
```

**In Fragment: Check if there is a current downloading instance**

```
fragmentCallback = activity as FragmentCallback

        if (fragmentCallback != null) {

            doAsync {
                var stillDownloading = fragmentCallback!!.getDownloadStatus(book_id)
                var maxPages = 0

                println("Stilldownloading: " + stillDownloading + " Book Id :" + book_id )

                if (stillDownloading) {

                    uiThread {
                        progressBar!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        progressText!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        maxPages = fragmentCallback!!.getMaxPages(book_id)
                        progressBar!!.max = maxPages
                        ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(
                                dloadButton!!,
                                ColorStateList.valueOf(getColorWrapper(activity, R.color.color_grey)))
                        dloadButton!!.isEnabled = false
                    }

                        while (stillDownloading) {
                            var dloadPage = fragmentCallback!!.getDownloadProgress(book_id)
                            if (dloadPage > 0) {

                                uiThread {
                                    progressBar!!.progress = dloadPage
                                    progressText!!.text = "Downloading page " + dloadPage + " of " + maxPages
                                }

                                stillDownloading = fragmentCallback!!.getDownloadStatus(book_id)

                            }
                        }

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: What have you done till yet and what do you want to implement? Please edit your question and clear the difference

Comment: `But when the user presses "back", the task stops` did you try overriding onBackpressed in your activity and remove super from it?